# RDMA WRITE and queue pair relationship?

Tags: rdma

Client and Server create a queue pair(RC mode), Server reg a large buffer on nic, then Client side use RDMA WRITE to write the remote large buffer on Server.

If I close queue pair on Server side, can I make sure that Client side's RDMA WRITE can't succeed through the closed queue pair? by the way, Client Side may consider the queue pair normal because we only close queue pair on Server Side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by “close” the QP, you mean destroy it, then it is correct that no more RDMA Write operations can be performed through that QP once the destroy operation returns. All incoming packets targeting that QP number (QPN) will be dropped by the server.

The client side may not find out that the QP has been destroyed until it attempts to send something on it; an RDMA Write will fail (complete with error status) and the client QP will transition to the error state.